# Refactoring LINQ to Entities queries with let variables and sub-queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to be able to somehow break up the following code:

```
return from e in _context.Employees
       let HasWatchedAllVideos = 
       (
           from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
           where ev.EmployeeId == e.Id && ev.EndTime.HasValue
           select ev.Id
       ).Count() == _context.Videos.Count()
       let EndTime = HasWatchedAllVideos ?
       (
           from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
           where ev.EmployeeId == e.Id
           select ev.EndTime
       ).Max() : null
       let StartTime =
       (
           from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
           where ev.EmployeeId == e.Id
           select ev.StartTime
       ).Min()
       select new EmployeeListItem
       {
           Id = e.Id,
           FirstName = e.FirstName,
           LastName = e.LastName,
           Company = e.Company,
           HasWatchedAllVideos = HasWatchedAllVideos,
           StartTime = StartTime,
           EndTime = EndTime
       };
```

For example, I am looking for a way to factor out:

```
let HasWatchedAllVideos = 
(
    from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
    where ev.EmployeeId == e.Id && ev.EndTime.HasValue
    select ev.Id
).Count() == _context.Videos.Count()
```

into a separate method for reusability purposes, yet I can't figure out exactly how to go about doing this. I have tried:

```
private bool HasWatchedAllVideos(int employeeId)
{
    return (from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
            where ev.EmployeeId == employeeId && ev.EndTime.HasValue
            select ev.Id
            ).Count() == _context.Videos.Count();
}
```

Which gives me my old favorite, 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method' exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [refactoring LINQ IQueryable expression to remove duplicated portions of queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769351/refactoring-linq-iqueryable-expression-to-remove-duplicated-portions-of-queries)

Answer (score 0):

This question probably won't get a lot of action, so I am posting a related question that has helped me try to find a better solution:

[refactoring LINQ IQueryable expression to remove duplicated portions of queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769351/refactoring-linq-iqueryable-expression-to-remove-duplicated-portions-of-queries)

Here's the code for my particular variation of a solution:

```
public class AdaTrainingService : ADATraining.Web.Models.IAdaTrainingService, IDisposable
{
    private ADATrainingEntities _context = new ADATrainingEntities();

    public IQueryable<EmployeeListItem> GetEmployeeListing()
    {
        return from e in _context.Employees
               join evsws in EmployeeVideoAggregatesView() on e.Id equals evsws.EmployeeId
               select new EmployeeListItem
               {
                   Id = e.Id,
                   FirstName = e.FirstName,
                   LastName = e.LastName,
                   Company = e.Company,
                   HasWatchedAllVideos = evsws.HasWatchedAllVideos,
                   StartTime = evsws.StartTime,
                   EndTime = evsws.EndTime
               };
    }

    private class EmployeeVideoSeriesWatchingStats
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool HasWatchedAllVideos { get; set; }
    }

    private IQueryable<EmployeeVideoSeriesWatchingStats> EmployeeVideoAggregatesView()
    {
        return from ev in _context.EmployeeVideos
               group ev by ev.EmployeeId into myGroup
               select new EmployeeVideoSeriesWatchingStats
               {
                   EmployeeId = myGroup.Key,
                   StartTime = myGroup.Min( x => x.StartTime),
                   EndTime = myGroup.Max( x => x.EndTime),
                   HasWatchedAllVideos = myGroup.Count() ==  _context.Videos.Count()
               };
    }   

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

-- UPDATE 5/13/2011 --

The example above performs an inner join and will not work for instances where you want to include all employees even if EmployeeVideoAggregatesView() returns no results, so to allow for left outer joining, I had to tweak the code a bit:

```
public IQueryable<EmployeeDetails> GetEmployeeListing()
{
    return from e in _context.Employees
           join evsws in EmployeeVideoAggregatesView() on e.Id equals evsws.EmployeeId into myJoin
           from mj in myJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new EmployeeDetails
           {
               Id = e.Id,
               FirstName = e.FirstName,
               LastName = e.LastName,
               Company = e.Company,
               BadgeNumber = e.BadgeNumber,
               Title = e.Title,
               HasWatchedAllVideos = (mj.HasWatchedAllVideos == null) ? false : mj.HasWatchedAllVideos,
               StartTime = mj.StartTime,
               EndTime = mj.EndTime
           };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// don't count every time
var totalCount = _context.Videos.Count();

from e in _context.Employees
let HasWatchedAllVideos =
    totalCount ==
    _context.EmployeeVideos.Count(ev => ev.EmployeeId == e.Id && ev.EndTime.HasValue)

// count just once per employee
let employeeVideos =  _context.EmployeeVideos.Count(ev => ev.EmployeeId == e.Id)

let EndTime = HasWatchedAllVideos ? employeeVideos.Max() : null
let StartTime =  HasWatchedAllVideos ? employeeVideos.Min() : null

select new EmployeeListItem
{
    Id = e.Id,
    FirstName = e.FirstName,
    LastName = e.LastName,
    Company = e.Company,
    HasWatchedAllVideos = HasWatchedAllVideos,
    StartTime = StartTime,
    EndTime = EndTime
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this isn't what I meant.

Comment: Let me be a little more explicate: I was trying to figure out a way to reuse parts of my query in other places. Your example is a cleaner (and I believe more performant) version of the one I originally posted, but has the same restraints I was trying to get around: namely that I can't factor out the concept of EndTime/StartTime/HasWatchedAllvideos into reusable chunks of code.

Comment: @Merritt: How about calculated index? Insert speed will degrade to count all videos, save min and max, but reading (it it occurs more often) speed will increase significantly, I guess.